# Plotting a shape with Google Satellite Image as basemap

Tags: python, geopandas

I am trying to generate a static image with the plot of a shape on top of a Google Satellite Image. After some research, I ended up doing so with Salem package, by following this example in its documentation: https://salem.readthedocs.io/en/v0.2.3/auto_examples/plot_googlestatic.html

I am facing to problems here:

1. For a reason I understand, the plot does not expand to the figure size. I set the figure background in black to make it visible that a frame appears.
2. The main problem I am facing is that the shape does not properly adapts to the image size. Whenever I change the size, the shape on it is not scaled as expected.

This is a reproducible example:

```
from shapely import wkt
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import salem
from salem import GoogleVisibleMap, Map

# Generation of a very simple shape (a square) for a reproducible example
df = pd.DataFrame({'Object': [1],
                    'geometry': ['POLYGON ((-4.00 38.00, -4.00 38.05, -4.05 38.05, -4.05 38.00, -4.00 38.00))']})
df['geometry'] = gpd.GeoSeries.from_wkt(df['geometry'])
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='geometry', crs='epsg:4326')


# Configure image aspect
size_x = 400
size_y = 400
dpi = 96

# read the shapefile and use its extent to define the map size
shp = salem.transform_geopandas(gdf)

# Get the Google Static image
g = GoogleVisibleMap(x=[shp.min_x, shp.max_x], y=[shp.min_y, shp.max_y],
                     scale=1,  # scale is for more details
                     maptype='satellite',
                     size_x=size_x, size_y=size_y
                    )

# the google static image is a standard rgb image
ggl_img = g.get_vardata()

sm = salem.Map(g.grid, nx=size_x, factor=1)
sm.set_rgb(ggl_img)  # add the background rgb image
sm.set_shapefile(shp, edgecolor='red', facecolor='blue', alpha=0.5, linewidth=2)

# prepare the figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(size_x/dpi,size_y/dpi), dpi=dpi)

# plot 1
sm.plot(ax=ax)
fig.patch.set_facecolor('black')
plt.savefig('test_400.png', dpi=dpi)
plt.show()
```

If I export the image setting at 400x400 or at 1000x1000 you can appreciate that the shape (the blue square) does not cover the same geographical area.

[image]
[image]

Do you know what is happening here?

Thank you

Comment: I don't have an answer but note that your usage of Google tiles violates their ToS.